# How do I compare the speed of two Javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have some Javascript that is reading in some XML.  There is an older function which was used to create a JSON object from that data, and I've written a new function that I hope will create that JSON object faster.
What is the easiest and best way to determine which function is performing faster?  It's a decent amount of data, so it's somewhat important to know.
Thanks.

Comment: I won't claim to know the best way, but some people like http://jsperf.com

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `console.time("ID");` and `console.timeEnd("ID");` (info [here](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API)), and look the results in the Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug like so:

```
console.time("oldFunc");
//oldfunc();
console.timeEnd("oldFunc");

console.time("newfunc");
//newfunc();
console.timeEnd("newfunc");
```

Also, you could use [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/)

Comment: From what I can tell, the order seems to matter: whatever function runs second will have a speed advantage.  Proof: run olfunc() against oldfunc(), newfunc() against newfunc().

Comment: @orson That's true. To solve this just run `oldFunc` once before running the two functions again.

Answer (score 4):

Some info on this and code sample [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120510155841/http://www.einternals.com/blog/web-development/javascript-find-script-execution-time-2)

```
var startDate = new Date(); 

// execute your tasks here
 
var endDate = new Date();
 
var timeTaken = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
 
alert('Time take to execute the script is '+timeTaken+' milliseconds');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(new Date).getTime();
```

This is how you get current time in milliseconds. Do that before and after execution of code, subtract and you have execution time in miliseconds.

Sample:

```
var start=(new Date).getTime();
//call your code
alert('Code took '+((new Date).getTime()-start)+'ms');
```

If your code organisation allows, you can make your call in a for loop, repeating n (let's say 1000) times and divide the time by n at the end.

This way you get the average speed, which is especially helpful if you function varies a lot (like network calls).

Comment: ... and then do it a thousand times on each version and take the minimum values as result.

Comment: Thanks, Bergi! That is good advice, if it that is possible to do in OP's case. Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like [John Resigs way](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-benchmark-quality/) of testing the performance of a function:

```
function runTest(name, test, next){
  var runs = [], r = 0;
  setTimeout(function(){
    var start = Date.now(), diff = 0;

    for ( var n = 0; diff < 1000; n++ ) {
      test();
      diff = Date.now() - start;
    }

    runs.push( n );

    if ( r++ < 4 )
      setTimeout( arguments.callee, 0 );
    else {
      done(name, runs);
      if ( next )
        setTimeout( next, 0 );
    }
  }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this in the browser or server-side?

If it's server-side, I'd recommend using your shell scripting tool of choice to do the benchmarking (linux has `time`, windows has...whatever windows has).

If it's in the browser, then you can always wrap a certain number of iterations (10,000 is usually enough) in:

```
var start = new Date.getTime();

var runs = 10000;

while (runs) {
    // do stuff here

    runs--;
}

console.log('Finished in ' + (new Date.getTime() - start) + ' ms.');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var d1 = new Date();     
 function1();
 var d2 = new Date();
 console.log("Function 1 : ", d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());

 function2();
 var d3 = new Date();
 console.log("Function 2 : ", d3.getTime() - d2.getTime());
```